# Running Perl Scripts on servers that don't have the modules

Tags: perl, package

I need to run a perl script to gather system information that will be deployed and executed on different unix servers.

Right now I am writing it and testing it, and I'm receiving this error.

> Can't locate XML/DOM.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5
>   /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl
>   /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at
>   test.pl line 7. BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at test.pl line 7.

So I am simply using XML::DOM which should be part of Perl but it isn't for this version on this particular server which is 5.10.1.

Anyways, is there a way I can create and design my script and package modules into it while keeping the .pl extension, which is the requirement for this script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the modules don't require compiled libraries, you can include them by copying the text out of the module into your .pl file. That's a horrible hack but it should work.

Perl modules should contain a package statement that gives them their name. When you get to your main program section you'll need a `package main;` statement of your own.

Comment: You can automate this with [`App::FatPacker`](https://metacpan.org/module/fatpack), but `XML::DOM` has XS dependencies.

Comment: Yep. Looks like it uses expat.

Comment: @envinyater: It will not work. You will need to find a XML module that uses only Perl, or you will need to find a way to unpack a directory tree containing the modules and libraries, instead of using a single .pl file.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the modules in any directory, and then include this directory to be included in the search for modules via [the `lib` pragma](http://perldoc.perl.org/lib.html). Be aware that a module `Foo::Bar` has to be in the file `MY-ROOT/Foo/Bar.pm` and may not be in `MY-ROOT/Bar.pm`, where `MY-ROOT` is your module directory.

```
use lib 'MY-ROOT';
use Foo::Bar;
```

However, this only works for pure-Perl modules, and doesn't support XS.

Answer (score 1):

In lieu of using the `lib` pragma as amon suggests, consider installing [perlbrew](http://perlbrew.pl/) and [cpanminus](https://metacpan.org/module/App%3a%3acpanminus) which is designed to work hand-in-hand to add and/or update modules.

`perlbrew` is designed to be leveraged by specifying `#!/usr/bin/env perl` as the interpreter line in your Perl scripts while adding a line like `source ~/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc` to your `${HOME}/.bash_profile` to locate the local version of Perl you want.